# Considering clean code and app performance, which implementation is better?

Tags: java

First option doesn't create a new object each time, but is less readable. Second, creates an object, but looks clean. PoolList size is about 20-28. Which one would you choose?

```
for (int i = 0; i < poolList.getPoolList().size(); i++){

        if (isTaskExecutable(poolList.getPoolList().get(i).getName()))
            callableList.add(new ConnectToApiCallable(this.appendPoolApiUrl(poolList.getPoolList().get(i)), poolList.getPoolList().get(i).getName(), poolList.getPoolList().get(i).getType()));
        else
            continue;
}
```

---

```
for (int i = 0; i < poolList.getPoolList().size(); i++){

        PoolDefinition poolDefinition = poolList.getPoolList().get(i);

        if (isTaskExecutable(poolDefinition.getName()))
            callableList.add(new ConnectToApiCallable(this.appendPoolApiUrl(poolDefinition), poolDefinition.getName(), poolDefinition.getType()));
        else
            continue;
}
```

Comment: Where are you creating the object in the first approach?

Comment: This question is more suitable for the code review StackExchange: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This seems to me like a question that would be better suited to the Code Review StackExchange, as this contains questions on preferred styles for *already functioning* code.  Also notice that the "implementation" tag on SO is in the process of being removed and should not be used.

Comment: The second one looks nicer and it doesn't seem to create any additional objects. Perhaps you are mistaking objects with variables?

Comment: As a general rule, legibility trumps everything else. Concerns about speed and memory are, more often than not, misplaced.

Comment: `else
            continue;` part is redundant

Comment: A wise coder once said, "there are at least two compilers that have to read your Java code: the Java compiler and the human brain; the second is the most important of the two."

Comment: "Second, creates an object" - no, it doesn't. The object already exists in the list. You didn't use `new` keyword to create the object. You only created a new variable which is going to consume 4 (or 8) bytes on the stack (regardless of the number of iterations).

Comment: You are right. I thought a new object was created, while it was only a reference variable.

Comment: Also, if that list is a `LinkedList` and is big, calling `get()` on it multiple times is a bad idea, as it has `O(n)` time complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second option does *not* create a new object. It simply creates a stack reference to the already existing object at `poolList.getPoolList().get(i)`. That way you do not have to repeatedly bear the overhead of calling `poolList.getPoolList().get(i)` to get that same object.

So the second option is actually cleaner *and* faster than the first.

Comment: Agree, but what about `faster` !? No proof

Comment: @Yahya Even without getting formal and going into implementation details, it is easy to prove that it is faster. `poolList.getPoolList().get(i)` requires two method calls, referencing a stack variable requires none.

Comment: @Yahya for practical purposes, "certainly not slower, but maybe the same when we're lucky or the optimizer is smart" means "faster"

Answer (score 1):

In fact, I could not see why Second Option would be faster, thus I did this test that simulates similar scenario:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private List<Person> friends;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        friends = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addFriend(Person person) {
        friends.add(person);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

   public List<Person> getFreinds(){
       return friends;
   }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] alphabet = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
        Random rand = new Random();
        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
            String name = "";
            for(int j=0; j<10; j++) {
                name += alphabet[rand.nextInt(26)];
            }       
            people.add(new Person(name, rand.nextInt(60)+10));
        }


        Person person = people.get(0);
        for(Person p : people) person.addFriend(p);


        final long startTime1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < person.getFreinds().size(); i++){
            person.getFreinds().get(i).getAge();
            person.getFreinds().get(i).getName();
        }
        final long endTime1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("First Option Using Method Chaining: " + (endTime1-startTime1) + " Milliseconds");


        final long startTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < person.getFreinds().size(); i++){
            Person friend = person.getFreinds().get(i);
            friend.getAge();
            friend.getName();
        }
        final long endTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Second Option Using Local Object: " + (endTime2-startTime2) + " Milliseconds");
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
First Option Using Method Chaining: 20 Milliseconds
Second Option Using Local Object: 17 Milliseconds
```

**Conclusion**

The test performed on one million elements and repeated many times giving same result:
Indeed, Two Methods Calls will cost *slightly* more time.